# Opening half screen activity on Home Screen after call ends

Tags: android

I am trying to open an activity which will cover half screen on Home Scree.
It will be called by BroadcastReceiver which will be triggered when call ends.
Problem I am facing is it opens the MAIN activity in the background and I am not able to get Home Screen.

Here is the code:

```
public class IncomingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {                                    // 1

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                                         // 2
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);                         // 3

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)) {                                  // 4
        Intent intent_new=new Intent(context, HalfScreen.class);
        intent_new.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent_new.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        context.startActivity(intent_new);
     }
   } 
}
```

Activity Class:

```
public class AddAppointmentHomeScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_appointment_home_screen_activity);
}
```

}

add_appointment_home_screen_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:windowAnimationStyle="@android:style/Animation.Translucent"
android:windowBackground="@android:color/transparent"
android:windowIsTranslucent="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest File:

```
<activity android:name=".AddAppointmentHomeScreenActivity" ></activity>
```

Please let me know if more details are required..

```
public class AddAppointmentHomeScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_appointment_home_screen_activity);
}
```

}

Comment: in manifest add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog"` to you activity.

Comment: it is still opening the MAIN activity in background

Comment: can you show your HalfScreen activity